# Image gets distorted when used as button image

Tags: ios, image, uibutton

I created an image which is intended to be used as background image of `UIButton`. This is what I get:

[image: Button icon]

The image looks great in Photoshop, but when used in iOS application as a button image it looks distorted(the lines are not strait and definitely not as smooth as in the original). How can I avoid this effect?

EDIT:// Preview window

[image]

Comment: Is the image the exact size of the button? Do you have 1x,2x,3x image sizes for it?

Comment: no, it isn't. Image is 512px tall and wide. You're saying that all images that I use must be imported in Assets.xcassets folder?  Is there any tool that  I can use that sets the appropriate tool for image resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that aspect ratios of button and image are the same?

Another thing - use appropriate image size for button image, e.g button view is 30px high, then you need add 30px(`@1x`), 60px(`@2x`) and 90px(`@3x`) images. If you just add an image with 1000px it won't look good, take more disk space and reduce performance.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. When I open an image in Preview, the size of an image@1x opened should be approximately the same as it would look on a iphone. Than I make the 2x and 3x variants which only have higher pixel density. Is this what it needs to be done?

Comment: If you want to get your images great - never approximate. So, as I said in my answer, let's assume that you've created a UIButton with square frame 30x30, if you support non-retina devices like iPad 2 and 1gen iPad mini, you should create a file named e.g `buttonImage.png` with dimensions 30x30, then you'll need to support retina devices, for those create a file named same as your original file but with `@2x`, like `buttonImage@2x.png` and with size 60x60 (same process with `@3x`). Remember that just stretching 30x30 picture to 60x60 won't help, you'll need better quality original image.

Comment: I added a screenshot of Preview window. The dimensions you are referring are in pixels? Also when I set dimensions of height and width in Attributes Inspector, those dimensions are equivalent to the number of pixels if 1x is used. If 2x image is used, than each point of height or width in Attr. Inspector is equivalent to 2 pixels? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are right, but I'll explain, when you enter dimensions in Attributes Inspector these dimensions are not in _pixels_, they are in _points_. One point represents one point on the device's screen, which is 1 pixel on non-retina devices, 2 pixels on retina devices and 3 pixels on retina-hd. That means when you say to Xcode that button's dimensions are 30x30 _points_ it will decide between `@1x` ,`@2x` or `@3x` image depending on what device you are running your app. And your task is to give Xcode all the images.